# Reading from plist to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I am trying to read and I also need to write to a plist.

So far I am trying to simply read the contents in.

Here is my appSettings.plist:

[image]

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"appSettings" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

I tried to do this:

```
NSArray *mruItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[tmp objectForKey:@"lastSearches"]];
```

But it throws an error. A check I did on the [tmp objectForKey:@"lastSearches"] type revealed this is not an NSArray...

How can I read the contents into my NSArray?

Thanks!

(I would love to have some info on writing too)

Comment: I may have made the lastSearches a dictionary rather than an Array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the screenshot above you see that it's pretty clear that "lastSearches" is a Dictionary, not a list. You can try to switch the type there to a Array type instead and it should work for you.

Another solution would be to iterate over the keys in that dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *lastSearches = [tmp objectForKey:@"lastSearches"];
for (NSString *key in lastSearches.allKeys)
{
  NSString *value = [lastSearches objectForKey:key];
}
```

Note that this would not be in order, and you probably would have to sort before iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it's not an array but a dictionary (look at your image).